# issue with replacing back to forward slash if it exists in string

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

I am struggling with the following:

```
    if(typeof value == "string" && value.match(/\/)){
        value = value.replace(/\\/g, "/");
    }
```

what I am trying to achieve is to find if string contains any back slash `\`. if yes I need to replace it with forward slash but the above does not work and gives me compilation error.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Backslash escapes the ending forward slash of your regex literal. Just double it: `value.match(/\\/)`

Comment: @CRice thanks but when I double it it does not catch this: abcd \n ssas. I expect \n 
 to be catched

Comment: `\n` is a new line.  The string will not include a literal `\\` in it.

Comment: @Taplar the reason I am doing this conversion is to catch all scenarios like \n \t . Is there any way I can change all keys like \n to /n ?

Comment: You would have to search for `\n`, rather than just \\ to catch that character.

Comment: Why do you need to do this in first place? What is the *real* input? `\n` inside a JavaScript string literal will result the string value to contain a line break. The string value won't *literally* contain the character sequence `\n`. Please [edit] your question to provide more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it may not make sense to replace escaped characters in a string, you could use [String.raw](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw) to ensure the escaped characters are treated as literals.

Snippet:

```js
let value = String.raw`luke\ abcd \n \t ssas\.`;

if (typeof value === "string" && value.match(/\\/)) {
  value = value.replace(/\\/g, "/");
}

console.info(value);
```

Comment: Thanks what does /u mean at the end of the match? (I know it is unicode but can you explain it in a simple word how it will help us there)

Comment: Also when I do this: let value = "luke\ abcd \n \t ssas\.";const rawValue= String.raw`${value}`; it seems that all \ gets removed. Am I missing anything?

Comment: ignore the /u - it was not needed

Comment: Thanks. How about this: Also when I do this: let value = "luke\ abcd \n \t ssas\.";const rawValue= String.raw${value}; it seems that all \ gets removed. Am I missing anything?

Comment: that syntax doesn't seem correct: `String.raw${value}; ` surely would need to be `let rawValue = String.raw`${value}`;  ` - also if you use `const`, you cannot change the value. tested using this and works fine

Comment: Ok how about this: const filePath = String.raw`${"C:\Development\profile\aboutme.html"}`;
console.log(`The file was uploaded from: ${filePath}`);
this removes all \. The point is I need to be able to pass an input which is a variable to the String.raw

Comment: no, clearly you can see that will error. just use ```String.raw`C:\Development\profile\aboutme.html`;```

Comment: Yes exactly when I use it this way ${value} it seems that it already converts the /n to new line so does not give a chance for conversion to /n
let value = `C:\Development\profile\aboutme.html`
console.log(String.raw`${value};`)
was wondering if there is a way to avoid it

Comment: no, I don't believe so and your question didn't mention any use of template params