# String.raw does not work as expected when I pass a variable

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am having an issue with string.raw. I have the following which works. Example got from : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw

```
// Create a variable that uses a Windows
// path without escaping the backslashes:
const filePath = String.raw`C:\Development\profile\aboutme.html`;

console.log(`The file was uploaded from: ${filePath}`);
// expected output: "The file was uploaded from: C:\Development\profile\aboutme.html"
```

but when I do the same but only using variable all \ are removed. How can I get the same result as above with using the following code:

```
// Create a variable that uses a Windows
// path without escaping the backslashes:
const filePath = String.raw`${"C:\Development\profile\aboutme.html"}`;

console.log(`The file was uploaded from: ${filePath}`);
// expected output: "The file was uploaded from: C:\Development\profile\aboutme.html"
 but I get "The file was uploaded from: C:Developmentprofileaboutme.html"
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Using `String.raw` on a variable doesn't make much sense, since the backslashes are already removed in that variable.

Comment: @Ivar here is the var I am sending and the bakcslashes are already there: ${"C:\Development\profile\aboutme.html"}

Comment: No, they're not. They're in the string _literal_, but as soon as that code gets parsed and the string is stored in memory, those backslashes are gone. You'll see if you log `"C:\Development\profile\aboutme.html"`.

Comment: @Ivar Can I use string.raw in a way that it does not remove the \. Here is the main issue I am trying to figure out
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63472978/issue-with-replacing-back-to-forward-slash-if-it-exists-in-string?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: @Ivar I am trying to convert \ to / using string literal for any incoming input to a function

Comment: You can use `String.raw` the way you did in your first code. But it _only_ works if you have the actual string in your source code. If you have the string inside a variable it is not possible, because those backslashes are already lost at that point.

Comment: No. In your example they are lost because the string is inside double quotes, and when the JavaScript engine parses your code, those backslashes are seen as escape characters and therefore removed. But I don't believe that this is your actual code. I assume that you get this string from somewhere, but you haven't shown where, so I can't really answer that. (If this is your actual code, then it doesn't really make sense not to use your first example.)

Comment: @Ivar I was trying to make a simple example to make it easier to discuss. In my code I need to pass it as an variable and not hard coded

Comment: In that case `String.raw` is not an option. The string that is stored in the variable has already lost those backslashes. You'll need to figure out where in the process of becoming a variable they went missing. Possibly you inserted the original path somewhere without properly escaping it first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I get the same result as above with using the following code

You can't, it's different code!

`String.raw` only works as a tag on template literals. The template literal in your second snippet is `` `${…}` ``, i.e. it has no actual content but only one interpolated value. (That value comes from a string literal expression, and `String.raw` has absolutely no effect on that). It's working the same as

```
const __temp = "C:\Development\profile\aboutme.html";
//                ^           ^       ^
const filePath = String.raw`${__temp}`;
```

The backlashes there are in a plain `"…"` string, and not escaped, and there's no way to bring them back.